# Overcome Marketo's quota limits

Tags: marketo

As far as I know, Marketo limits the number of REST API requests to 10,000 per day. Is there a way to overcome this limit? Can I pay and get more of those?

I found out that the REST API requests and the SOAP API requests counts separately but I'm trying to find a solution that is limited to REST API.

Moreover, in order to get an access token I need to sacrifice a request. I need to know how long this access token will be alive in order to save as much requests as possible.

Comment: You should probably ask Marketo about this instead.

Comment: Marketo encourages to ask questions about their API on stackoverflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can increase your limit just by asking your account manager. It costs about 15K per year to increase your limit by 10K API calls.

Here are the default limits in case you don't have them yet:

**Default Daily API Quota:** 10,000 API calls (counter resets daily at 12:00 AM CST)

**Rate Limit:** 100 API calls in a 20 second window

[Documentation: REST API](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to ask your Marketo account manager about this.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would update this with some more information since I get this question a lot:

http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/
Daily Quota: Most subscriptions are allocated 10,000 API calls per day (which resets daily at 12:00AM CST).  You can increase your daily quota through your account manager.
Rate Limit: API access per instance limited to 100 calls per 20 seconds.
Concurrency Limit:  Maximum of 10 concurrent API calls.

For the Daily limit:

Option 1:  Call your account manager.   This will cost you $'s.   For a client I work for we have negotiated a much higher limit.

Option 2:  Store and Batch your records.  For example, you can send a batch of 300 leads in a single lead insert/update call.  Which means you can insert/update 3,000,000 leads per day.

For the Rate limit:

Option 1 will probably not work.   Your account manager will be reluctant to change this unless you a very large company.

Option 2:  You need to add some governance to your code.  There are several ways to do this, including queues, timers with a counter, etc.   If you make multi-threaded calls, you will need to take into account concurrency etc.

Concurrent call limit:
You have to limit your concurrent threads to 10.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle API Quota limits.

1. If you all together want to avoid hitting API limit, try to achieve your functionality thru Marketo Webhooks.  Marketo webhook will not have API limits, but it has its own CONS.  Please research on this.
2. You may use REST API, but design your strategy to batch the maximum records in a single payload instead of smaller chunks, e.g. sending 10 different API calls with each 20 records, accumulate the max allowed payload and call Marketo API once.

Answer (score 0):

The access token is valid for 1 hour after authenticating.

Marketo's Bulk API can be helpful in regard to rate limiting as once you have the raw activities the updates, etc on the lead object can be done without pinging marketo for each lead: http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/bulk-extract/ however be aware of export limits that you may run into when bulk exporting lead + activities. Currently, Marketo only counts the size of the export against the limit when the job has been completed which means you can launch a max of 2 concurrent export jobs(which sum to more than the limit) at the same time as a workaround. Marketo will not kill a running job if a limit has been reached so long as the job was launched prior to the limit being reached.

Answer (score 0):

Marketo has recently upgraded the maximum limit

**Daily Quota:** Subscriptions are allocated 50,000 API calls per day (which resets daily at 12:00AM CST).  You can increase your daily quota through your account manager.

**Rate Limit:** API access per instance limited to 100 calls per 20 seconds.
Concurrency Limit:  Maximum of 10 concurrent API calls.

https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/